# Latex real textwidth smaller than \textwidth in documentclass article but not in report

Tags: margins

I am seeing a weird behavior in the textwidth in Latex. When I use \documentclass[a4paper]{article} the actual text width do not really all the \textwidth. I can see that if I use showframes in geometry. The problem does not occur in \documentclass[a4paper]{report}.

example 1:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in,showframe]{geometry} % to change the page dimensions top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in,
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\title{TEST}
\author{?}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\abstract{???}
\tableofcontents
\newpage


\section{Introduction}\label{sec:Introdu}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

example 2:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in,showframe]{geometry} % to change the page dimensions top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in,
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\title{TEST}
\author{?}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\abstract{???}
\tableofcontents
\newpage


\section{Introduction}\label{sec:Introdu}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: article]

[image: report]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In article class abstract is an environment that typesets the abstract in a narrower width. `\abstract` is equivalent to `\begin{abstract}` so you never really end the abstract, thus the entire doc is typeset in a narrower width.

Use

```
\begin{abstract} 
... 
 \end{abstract}
```

Comment: @Courvoisier If this solved your problem, then mark the answer as accepted. I've seen this issue before. It is a bit annoying that some classes issues the abstract as a macro argument while most does it as an environment

Comment: Couldn't accept before some time for some reason. Thanks for the quick reply